# Xamarin forms: out of memory exception after image integration

Tags: xamarin.forms

Developing a cross plattform app using Xamarin forms and FreshMVVM, I have been placing several images as clickable icons (ranging from 2KB to 80KB filesize with decent resolution for smooth edges). At a certain point when inserting new images, existing ones start vanishing from the GUI at runtime (even entire GUI areas) and the application eventually crashes with an OOM exception. Is there any best practice advice when dealing with images and overall app performace enhancement in a Xamarin environment in general? I don't consider my app pretty huge and can't hold back my disappointment of such a poor performance considering the size of my app.

Any advice apart from scaling down image resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading (check documentation, there is everything you need, for example: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#downsampling-properties)

Comment: Nice one. Works like a charme. Thanks =)